# Using union and count(*) together in SQL query

Tags: sql, union

I have a SQL query, looks something like this:

```
select name, count (*) from Results group by name order by name
```

and another, identical which loads from a archive results table, but the fields are the same.

```
select name, count (*) from Archive_Results group by name order by name
```

How would I combine the two in just one query? (So the group by would still function correctly). I tried with union all, however it won't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
SELECT tem.name, COUNT(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT name FROM results
  UNION ALL
  SELECT name FROM archive_results
) AS tem
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Thank you. All what I was missing was the "as tem" part ... Forgot that I have to name the "table" I create in order for this to work.

Comment: This will give the wrong answer. In fact, it will give a count of 1 for every name, because UNION is by default UNION DISTINCT.

Use UNION ALL.

Comment: Thank you Steve Kass, however I already knew that I needed to use UNION ALL. As stated above all what I was missing was the "as" term.

Comment: @Rekreativc: No problem. I commented because you marked the solution as Best Answer, and I didn't want future readers to think it was a correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

If you have supporting indexes, and relatively high counts, something like this may be considerably faster than the solutions suggested:

```
SELECT name, MAX(Rcount) + MAX(Acount) AS TotalCount
FROM (
  SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS Rcount, 0 AS Acount
  FROM Results GROUP BY name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT name, 0, count(*)
  FROM Archive_Results
  GROUP BY name
) AS Both
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: FYI that I hit 'Both' as a reserved word.  MySQL 5.1 (btw)

Comment: I think instead of maintaining two columns, SUM(Count) would work as well.

Answer (score 9):

Is your goal...

1. To count all the instances of "Bob
   Jones" in both tables (for example)
2. To count all the instances of "Bob
   Jones" in `Results` in one row and
   all the instances of "Bob Jones" in
   `Archive_Results` in a separate row?

Assuming it's #1 you'd want something like...

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT name FROM Results UNION ALL SELECT name FROM Archive_Results)
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: what about case 2?

Comment: For #2, you're probably better off just running two queries and consolidating them in software. But you could also just do `SELECT name, COUNT(1) FROM Results GROUP BY name UNION SELECT name, COUNT(1) FROM Archive_Results` if you absolutely had to union the two.

Answer (score 2):

```
select T1.name, count (*)
from (select name from Results 
      union 
      select name from Archive_Results) as T1
group by T1.name order by T1.name
```

Comment: What does your answer add to the preceding ones?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(*) 
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM IP_IRRADIATE_SUBMISSION_PHOTON WHERE IRRADIATESUBMISSIONMASTERID = 84                        
  UNION SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM IP_IRRADIATE_SUBMISSION_ELECTRON WHERE IRRADIATESUBMISSIONMASTERID = 84
);
```

This worked in Oracle.  The "As TMP" was throwing it.  Slightly different query in that in sums several rows of counts.