# MySQL Get 'Most Active User' From Multiple Table

Tags: mysql

If i have multiple tables like on the picture below, then I want to get the most active user (counted from posted_by column), for example on this picture Mike is the most active user, what query should i run? Thank you 
[image]

Comment: Yes, but i dont get the correct query yet, any suggestion?

Comment: here: [How to do a count on a union query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731655/how-to-do-a-count-on-a-union-query)

Comment: [Using union and count together in SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266666/using-union-and-count-together-in-sql-query)

Comment: Thank you John Woo, you are the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT posted_by, count(*) AS total 
FROM(SELECT posted_by FROM article
UNION ALL
SELECT posted_by FROM ebook
UNION ALL
SELECT posted_by FROM forum_thread) AS counted
GROUP BY posted_by 
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all tables got the columns, you can use `UNION ALL`. Also I suggest to use `UserID` on posted_by field instead of name. If you want to output the name just join the tables with user table.

Comment: You should used `UNION ALL` instead as it would allow duplicates. Using `UNION` might wipe off the top user as it would get just a single record for all users who posted, even when they posted multiple times.